# Flask: Redirect using url_for with parameter "next" not working when the flow goes through multiple routes

Tags: python, flask

I have 5 routes A, B, C, D, E. Normally B => D, D => E (using redirect url_for). Now I want A => B => D => E => C.

In route A I have tried using

```
return redirect(url_for('B', next='C'))
```

but it just stops at route E instead of continuing to route C.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.url_for), I don't see that `url_for()` accepts a `next=` argument.  What do you expect the `next=` argument to do?  Where did you see an example of the function used that way?

Comment: @JohnGordon I have successfully use it to when I want to continue to route C if route B does not lead to D. For example this line works just fine, because route "login" doesn't lead to any other route. `return redirect(url_for('main_view.login', next='/payment/stripe_pay_flow/'+str(planid)))` but when it comes to main_view.register instead, it doesn't work anymore because register route leads to OTP input page. Login route does not.